# Passing date parameters from Json as event with angular-bootstrap-calendar

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, json

I'm using [Angular-Bootstrap-Calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar#documentation) to create an event calendar, the idea is for the events to be stored in a database. Anyway, in order to get events I'm getting the data from a MySQL database with PHP and sending them directly to the Calendar's controller using the JSON format like so:

```
    $date = $row['date_activity']; 
    $start = $row['starthour'];
    $start_date = date('D M d Y H:i:s O',strtotime("$date $start"));
    $end = $row['endhour'];
    $end_date = date('D M d Y H:i:s O',strtotime("$date $end"));
    $acttitle = $row['title_activity'];  

    $arr[] = array('startsAt' => $start_date,
    'endsAt'=>$end_date,
    'title'=>$acttitle,
    'type'=>'warning');
```

And calling that in the controller with:

```
    viewControllers.controller('calendarioController',['$scope','$http','$stateParams', function($scope, $http, moment, alert) {

    $scope.calendarView = 'month';
    $scope.viewDate = new Date();
    $http.get('activities.php').success(function(output){
       $scope.placeholder = output;
       console.log($scope.placeholder);
       });
    }]);
```

The console log brings out the objects with the proper content, but when I try to call the events on the calendar, it tells me the dates are not in Javascript format, and doesn't work. Is there a way I can store the results from the http.get and then create an event array within the controller definition?
Just for reference, this is the format for events using angular-bootstrap-calendar

```
    $scope.events = [
      {
      title: 'My event title', // The title of the event
      type: 'info', // The type of the event (determines its color). Can be important, warning, info, inverse, success or special
      startsAt: new Date(2013,5,1,1), // A javascript date object for when the event starts
      endsAt: new Date(2014,8,26,15), // Optional - a javascript date object for when the event ends
editable: false, // If edit-event-html is set and this field is explicitly set to false then dont make it editable.
      deletable: false, // If delete-event-html is set and this field is explicitly set to false then dont make it deleteable
      draggable: true, //Allow an event to be dragged and dropped
      resizable: true, //Allow an event to be resizable
      incrementsBadgeTotal: true, //If set to false then will not count towards the badge total amount on the month and year view
      recursOn: 'year', // If set the event will recur on the given period. Valid values are year or month
      cssClass: 'a-css-class-name' //A CSS class (or more, just separate with spaces) that will be added to the event when it is displayed on each view. Useful for marking an event as selected / active etc
    }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured a way around it by overwriting the $scope.event[] atribute inside the controller:

```
    $scope.events = output;
       console.log($scope.events);
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
           $scope.events[i].startsAt = new Date($scope.events[i].startsAt);
           $scope.events[i].endsAt = new Date($scope.events[i].endsAt);

    }
```